# <ServerException>Layer(s) not valid</ServerException> Republishing WMS layers in QGIS Server

Tags: qgis-server

I have a QGIS project that republishes several WMS services in QGIS Server.  The layer sources are WMS and the published layers are WMS.  I am getting the response Layer(s) not valid when I try to view the resulting services in a browser.  I have proven that my QGIS project configuration does work on a different server of the similar configuration (all software and versions are the same), however when I have tried to publish to my live server I have run into this problem.  If I remove the WMS layers the problem does not occur.  I conclude there is something about this instance of QGIS server or Apache that is causing the issue.  I have tried enabling CORS on Apache server in case that was a "cause" but it had no effect.

How can I further identify the source of this error?

Running QGIS Server 3.22 on Apache2 / Debian platform.  QGIS 3.22 desktop used for project config.

Log file:/apache2/error.log

> 13:26:56 CRITICAL Server[5213]: Error, Layer(s) Base_Layer_52733fdc_97c1_4959_aba9_bbb5b17b2e73, Coverages_58c4c894_941a_4c5b_bd85_f30821f9cea8, Soundings_97a00dd7_6415_4c69_93aa_eb42fbb01979 not valid in project /home/qgis/projects/enc.qgs
> 13:26:56 WARNING Server[5213]: 
> Layer(s) not valid

Comment: you need to check the log, but it is possible a network configuration or firewall issue preventing the server seeing the remote WMS server

Comment: I am able to run a curl request to the capabilities document of the remote service for the QGIS-Server server. The most useful log file I have found is now in the main description.